# Repository Pattern and UnitOfWork called from within class

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am quite new to the repository pattern and can see the benefits quite clearly. However the UnitOfWork class in my opinion makes things quite messy to call (when filter options are passed in to the db calls)

I would like to pass this unitOfWork object in to my data objects and let them handle the messy stuff.

For example if I had a Customer, Address and Account objects I would like to let the Account object handle the fetching and saving of its child objects (Customer and Address) and also handle the fetching of the data so that there could be a number of overloads for GetAccounts() taking various parameters to enable filtering.

However as I am new to this pattern I am not sure this is a good way of handling it. Is what I am planning to do considered poor programming? Or is it a perfectly acceptable way to use the repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Unit of Work shouldn't be messy, it just enables operations such as several operation on repositories to be made atomically.

A common criticism about Repository pattern is that it is sometimes overused when you actually use an ORM such as EF that implements it and that you are most likely to never have to change for a different one. Even more, at least EF also provides you a Unit of Work so you wouldn't need it either.

Once that you are sure that you want to use both, you'll have to chose how you want to retrieve data from your repositories. Actually, which entities get to have their own repository? Are you using DDD? Then, you probably want to provide repositories only for your aggregates and handle the rest through methods on them, encapsulating the business logic. For instance, you may decide that `Customer` is an aggregate root containing `Account` objects. If that'd be the case, then a `Customer.GetAccounts()` makes perfect sense, or maybe even just a collection of `Accounts`.

By the way, for filtering I'd suggest something like receiving a list of `Filter` objects to avoid overpopulated interfaces.

I'm sorry if I seem vague but it is quite an extensive subject and solutions depend heavily on your domain, its complexity and requirements.

Comment: By messy, I mean when wanting to filter then I am having to pass in lambda expressions in to the Get Methods. This is fine to a point but not all programmers (especially junior ones) are good with lambda expressions so it would be nice to hide all that behind a class. So Customer.GetNewCustomers(datetime dateEnrolled) could be called and within that method the lambda expression is then built. I am using Entity Framework though, I didn't think this implemented the repository pattern fully.

Answer (score 0):

> However the UnitOfWork class in my opinion makes things quite messy to call (when filter options are passed in to the db calls)

Unit-of-Work pattern isn't used when you pass filter options into the db calls.

**The main responsibility of [Unit-of-Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) is handling of Business Transactions.**

> "A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work." by Martin Fowler

[image]

**Retrieving data from your data source (e.g. Data Base) using query specifications is a responsibility of your [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).**

> if I had a Customer, Address and Account objects I would like to let the Account object handle the fetching and saving of its child objects (Customer and Address) and also handle the fetching of the data so that there could be a number of overloads for GetAccounts() taking various parameters to enable filtering.

If you want to let the `Account` object handle the fetching and saving of its child objects (Customer and Address then **it will be similar to [Active Record pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) when `an object carries both data and behavior`.**

[image: Active Record]

If you want to split data and behavior responsibilities between `domain model` and `data access layer` **you can move all data responsibilities to `AccountRepository` class since your `Account` entity looks like [AggregateRoot](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html).**